# how to change double "OO" existed words in the paragraph into green square in react? for example clooney - cl[green square]ey

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { modifiedPar: "", newPar: "modified paragraph will be here"};
  }

  greenMaker = word => {
      var newWord = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] + word[i+1] === "oo") {
          newWord += "[green]";
        } else if (word[i] + word[i-1] === "oo") {
          newWord += "";
        } else if (word === "door") {
          newWord = "door";
        } else {
          newWord += word[i];
        }
      }
      return newWord;
    }

  ezEngReader = par => {
    var greenMakerVar = this.greenMaker(par);
    return greenMakerVar;
  }

  handleFormInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      modifiedPar: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      newPar: this.ezEngReader(this.state.modifiedPar)
    })
  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>EZEngReader</h1>
          <textarea
            name=""
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleFormInput}
            className="form-control"
            id=""
            placeholder="write or paste your text here"
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>submit</button>
          <p style={{fontSize: "20px"}}>{this.state.newPar}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

hi there, I would like to make an app, when the user type or paste paragraph if there any word that exists double "OO" letters changes to green square. I have a function now which changes "OO" into [green] (with the letters), but i need to change it into green square. for example when user types "clooney" it has to change it to "cl[green square]ey"

Comment: well how have you decided to implement `green square` first of all? is it like a fontawesome icon or what?

Comment: hi TKoL, no I would like to get real green square shape now thru fontawesome icon

Answer (score 0):

Try: `word.replace(/oo/gi, '[green square]');`

Comment: hi MetallimaX thank you for your quick respond, I would like to change it double "oo" into actual green square shape, please do you have any hints?

Comment: With react it's a bit touchy to introduce HTML in your strings. Let's say you generate some `<span class="green-square" />` instead of [green square]. You will need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to inject that into a React component.

Answer (score 0):

I created this code to show you how you can use `.split` and `.map` to achieve what you want:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FontAwesomeIcon from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export default class Hello extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { modifiedPar: "", newPar: "modified paragraph will be here"};
  }

  greenMaker = word => {
    const wordAreas = word.split('oo');
    const newWords = wordAreas.flatMap(word => [word, 'oo']);
    newWords.pop(); // remove the last 'oo'
    return newWords.map(word => {
      if (word == 'oo') {
        return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-square" size="lg" />
      }
      return <span>{word}</span>;
    })
  }

ezEngReader = par => {
  var greenMakerVar = this.greenMaker(par);
  return greenMakerVar;
}

handleFormInput = e => {
  this.setState({
    modifiedPar: e.target.value
  })
}

handleSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({
    newPar: this.ezEngReader(this.state.modifiedPar)
  })
}

componentWillMount() {

}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>EZEngReader</h1>
        <textarea
          name=""
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleFormInput}
          className="form-control"
          id=""
          placeholder="write or paste your text here"
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>submit</button>
        <p style={{fontSize: "20px"}}>{this.state.newPar}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

You can see it in action here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fontawesome-5-playground-forked-p90qs

The basic flow is to split based on 'oo', so `hellooworld` would become `['hell','world']`.

Then the flatmap section adds an 'oo' after every entry, `['hell','oo','world','oo']`,

then I remove the last 'oo' since that will generally be unecessary.

Then I map each entry in that array -- if it's 'oo' I do my fontawesome icon, otherwise i render it into a `span`.

Then I return that array of React elements, which I render directly.

Comment: greenMaker = (word) => {
    const wordAreas = word.split("oo");
    const newWords = wordAreas.flatMap((word) => [word, "oo"]);
    newWords.pop(); // remove the last 'oo'
    return newWords.map((word) => {
      if (word == "oo") {
        return <span className="box green"></span>; // style.css which gives green filled square
        // return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-square" size="lg" />;
      }
      return <span>{word}</span>;
    });
  }; thanks much.when i use <p>or<span>tags 1st showing me green square and word. for ex: clooney ==> [ green filled sq]blmy